# How to make my Home Page of the site look the same on all screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So here is my code. I view this on my desktop screen and it looks like this.

[image: Site as viewed from my browser screen]

Also I noticed on inspecting, the relative size of different elements change on changing the resolution. I want to make it look all the same on any resolution or at least the the black box menus should remain at the same place irrespective of the page height. Be it 1080p or 4k.
But it doesn't happen.

for instance [FitnessBlender](https://www.fitnessblender.com/) has made it's page look all the same on increasing the page width or height.

Please help me with my code. Thanks

```css
/*Global Styling Start*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');


html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

/*Global Styling End*/
/* Header Styling Start*/

header{
    background-image: url(https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3T675LQ2ui6Rg7Zz9yKoyx/68257fa4d725f1f23ba39eba08f0e6f8/free-education-images.jpg?fit=fill&w=840&h=350);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    z-index: 2;
}

#header-text{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 15px;
    align-items: center;
}

#header-text > img{
    width: 60px;
}

h1{
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Courier New';
}

h1 > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

#nav-links{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 500px;
}

#nav-links > li{
    display: inline;
}

#nav-links > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-links > li > a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/*Header Styling End*/
/*TypeWriter Styling Start*/

#typewriter{
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    padding: 150px 25px 50px 0;
    position: relative;
}

#type-text{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-right: 4px solid orange;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

#type-text::before{
    animation: typing 20s linear infinite forwards ;
    content: "";
}



@keyframes typing {
    00.0% {content: "W";}
    00.5% {content: "We";}
    01.0% {content: "Wel";}
    01.5% {content: "Welc";}
    02.0% {content: "Welco";}
    02.5% {content: "Welcom";}
    03.0% {content: "Welcome";}
    03.5% {content: "Welcome ";}
    04.0% {content: "Welcome t";}
    04.5% {content: "Welcome to";}
    05.0% {content: "Welcome to ";}
    05.5% {content: "Welcome to I";}
    06.0% {content: "Welcome to IC";}
    06.5% {content: "Welcome to ICS";}
    07.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE";}
    07.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE ";}
    08.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE S";}
    08.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE St";}
    09.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Stu";}
    09.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Stud";}
    10.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study";}
    10.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study ";}
    11.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study M";}
    11.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study Ma";}
    12.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study Mat";}
    12.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study Mate!";}
    20.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study Mate!";}
    20.5% {content: "Welcome to ICSE Study ";}
    21.0% {content: "Welcome to ICSE ";}
    21.5% {content: "Welcome to ";}
    22.0% {content: "Welcome ";}
    22.5% {content: ". ";}
    23.0% {content: "R";}
    23.5% {content: "Re";}
    24.0% {content: "Rea";}
    24.5% {content: "Read";}
    25.0% {content: "Ready";}
    25.5% {content: "Ready ";}
    26.0% {content: "Ready t";}
    26.5% {content: "Ready to";}
    27.0% {content: "Ready to ";}
    27.5% {content: "Ready to L";}
    28.0% {content: "Ready to Le";}
    28.5% {content: "Ready to Lea";}
    29.0% {content: "Ready to Lear";}
    29.5% {content: "Ready to Learn";}
    30.0% {content: "Ready to Learn?";}
    37.5% {content: "Ready to Learn?";}
    38.0% {content: "Ready to ";}
    38.5% {content: "Ready ?";}
    39.0% {content: "Ready ";}
    39.5% {content: ".";}
    40.0% {content: "R";}
    40.5% {content: "Re";}
    41.0% {content: "Rea";}
    41.5% {content: "Read";}
    42.0% {content: "Read ";}
    42.5% {content: "Read t";}
    43.0% {content: "Read th";}
    43.5% {content: "Read the";}
    44.0% {content: "Read the ";}
    44.5% {content: "Read the B";}
    45.0% {content: "Read the Bl";}
    45.5% {content: "Read the Blo";}
    46.0% {content: "Read the Blog";}
    46.5% {content: "Read the Blog ";}
    47.0% {content: "Read the Blog f";}
    47.5% {content: "Read the Blog fo";}
    48.0% {content: "Read the Blog for";}
    48.5% {content: "Read the Blog for ";}
    49.0% {content: "Read the Blog for s";}
    49.5% {content: "Read the Blog for st";}
    50.0% {content: "Read the Blog for stu";}
    50.5% {content: "Read the Blog for stud";}
    51.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study";}
    51.5% {content: "Read the Blog for study ";}
    52.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study t";}
    52.5% {content: "Read the Blog for study ti";}
    53.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study tip";}
    53.5% {content: "Read the Blog for study tips!";}
    54.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study tips!";}
    60.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study tips!";}
    61.0% {content: "Read the Blog for study ";}
    61.5% {content: "Read the Blog for ";}
    62.0% {content: "Read the Blog ";}
    62.5% {content: "Read the ";}
    63.0% {content: "Read ";}
    63.5% {content: ".";}
    64.0% {content: "E";}
    64.5% {content: "Ev";}
    65.0% {content: "Eve";}
    65.5% {content: "Even";}
    66.0% {content: "Even ";}
    66.5% {content: "Even y";}
    67.0% {content: "Even yo";}
    67.5% {content: "Even you";}
    68.0% {content: "Even you ";}
    68.5% {content: "Even you c";}
    69.0% {content: "Even you ca";}
    69.5% {content: "Even you can";}
    70.0% {content: "Even you can ";}
    70.5% {content: "Even you can b";}
    71.0% {content: "Even you can be";}
    71.5% {content: "Even you can be ";}
    72.0% {content: "Even you can be a";}
    72.5% {content: "Even you can be a ";}
    73.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"";}
    73.5% {content: "Even you can be a \"T";}
    74.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"To";}
    74.5% {content: "Even you can be a \"Top";}
    75.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"Topp";}
    75.5% {content: "Even you can be a \"Toppe";}
    76.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"Topper";}
    76.5% {content: "Even you can be a \"Topper\"";}
    77.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"Topper\"!";}
    84.0% {content: "Even you can be a \"Topper\"!";}
    84.5% {content: "Even you can be a ";}
    85.0% {content: "Even you can be ";}
    85.5% {content: "Even you can ";}
    86.0% {content: "Even you ";}
    86.5% {content: "Even ";}
    87.0% {content: ".";}
    87.5% {content: "E";}
    88.5% {content: "Ex";}
    89.0% {content: "Exp";}
    89.5% {content: "Expl";}
    90.0% {content: "Explo";}
    90.5% {content: "Explor";}
    91.0% {content: "Explore";}
    91.5% {content: "Explore!";}
    98.5% {content: "Explore!";}
    99.0% {content: "Explore";}
    99.5% {content: ".";}
    100%{content: ".";}
}

@keyframes blink {
    0%{border-color: orange;}
    50%{border-color: transparent;}
    100%{border-color: orange;}
}

/*TypeWriter Styling End*/
/*Main Content Styling Start*/

/*Image Container Styling Start*/

#image-container{
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#image-container > img{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
/*Image Container Styling End*/

/*Floating Menu STyling Start*/

#content-holder{
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    height: 700px;
}
#content{
    background-image: url(https://educationalexploration.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/cropped-triangle-background-17.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 550px;
}

#p{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.315);    
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 650px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#ext-link{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

#ext-link > ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 900px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#ext-link > ul > a > li{
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#ext-link > ul > a{
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
   color: white;
   height: 150px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

#ext-link a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
}

#ext-link h5{
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#ext-link a:hover h5{
    font-size: 19px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#ext-link p{
    font-size: 12px;
}

#bor{
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

/*Floating Menu Styling End*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ICSE Study Mate</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="header-text">
                <img src="https://icsestudymate.files.wordpress.com/2020/08/wp-1596799613003.jpg" alt="ICSESM">
                <h1><a href="./home.html">ICSE StudyMate</a></h1>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul id="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Planners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Study Material</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div id="content-holder">
                <!--TypeWriter Animated Text and Description-->
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="typewriter">
                        <span id="type-text"></span>
                        <div id="image-container">
                        <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/788-7885220_fill-out-the-following-form-to-sign-up.png" alt="Students">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div id="p">
                        <p style="color: rgb(230, 230, 230);">We are ICSE StudyMate. Our Work is to provide you with study material free of cost.
                         You can get notes, pdfs, time tables, planners, etc. over here which will help you in
                         your studies.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Floating Menu-->
                <div id="ext-link"> 
                    <ul>
                        <a href="#" id="bor">
                            <li>
                                <h5>From the Founder</h5>
                                <p>Get an inpirational and Motivational Story!</p>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="bor">
                            <li>
                                <h5>Boards Class X</h5>
                                <p>What's up for this session's board exam?</p>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="bor">
                            <li>
                                <h5>2020 Batch News</h5>
                                <p>Are the results even comming :(</p>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                            <li>
                                <h5>Revised Syllabus</h5>
                                <p>Syllabus not reduced? No Worries!</p>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Testing Text-->
            <div>
                <p style="padding: 500px;">Out Test Text</p>
                <p>T2</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for media queries to add breakpoints where the design should change for specific screen sizes https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @jona Media Queries are fine but if I inspect the page and then change the height/width of the page, the black box menu doesn't remain at it's relative position unlike that of the site I mentioned in my question. It's position is same at every height. For example if I inspect my page and change the height from 768px, the black box menu just disappears on decreasing or just reveals fully on increasing the height. In the reference website mentioned in my question it's totally different. Even on changing the height at time of inspection, the black box always has it's 1/8th part visible.

Comment: The FitnessBlender page you reference sets the height of the `.masthead.home-masthead` div using `height: calc(100vh - 190px);` so that there will always be part of black blocks always showing for a laptop or desktop display. FitnessBlender uses media queries as @jona pointed out for when a user is visiting the site with a smartphone or tablet.

Comment: Thanks @RichDeBourke I found out thee solution. Thanks Very Much